# What's the speediest web hosting choices out there that are scalable to large traffic spikes and can handle fast page loads?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, cloud-hosting, buddypress

Is cloud hosting the way to go? Or is there something better that delivers fast page loads?

The reason I ask is because I run a buddypress site on a bluehost dedicated server, but it seems to run slow at most times of the day. This scares me because at the moment the sites not live and I'm afraid when it gets traffic it'll become worse and my visitors will lose interest. I use Amazon Cloud to handle all my media, JS, and CSS files along with a catching plugin, but it still loads slow at times.

I feel like the problem is Bluehost, because I visit other sites running buddypress and their sites seem to load instantly. Im not web hosting savvy so can someone please point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1):

The hosting choice depends on many factors such as technical requirements, growth rates, burst rates, budgets and more.

**Bigger Hardware**

To scale up hosting operation, your first choice is often just using a more powerful server, VPS, or cloud instance.  The point is not so much cloud vs. dedicated but that you simply bring more compute power to the problem.  Cloud can make scaling up easier - often with a few clicks.

**Division of Labor**

The next step often is division of labor. You offload database, static content, caching or other items to specific servers or services.  For example, you could offload static content to a CDN.  You could a dedicated database.

Once again, cloud vs non-cloud is not the issue.  The point is to bring more resources to your hosting problems.

**Pick the Right Application Stack**

I cannot stress enough picking the right underlying technology for your needs.  For example, I've recently helped a client switch from a Apache/PHP stack to a Varnish/Nginx/PHP-FPM stack for a very business Wordpress operation (>100 million page views/mo).  This change boosted capacity by nearly 5X with modest hardware changes.

**Same App. Different Story**

Also just because you are using a specific application, it does not mean the same hosting setup will work for you. I don't know about the specific app you are using but with Drupal, Wordpress, Joomla, Vbulletin and others, the plugins, site design, themes and other items are critical to overall performance.

To complicate matter, user behavior is something to consider as well. Consider a discussion form that has a 95:1 read:post ratio.  What if you do something in the design to encourage more posts and that ratio moves to 75:1.  That means more database writes, less caching, etc.

In short, details matter, so get a good understanding of your application before you start to scale out hosting.

Answer (score 0):

A hosting service is part of the solution. Another part is proper server configuration.

For instance [this guy](http://www.ewanleith.com/blog/900/10-million-hits-a-day-with-wordpress-using-a-15-server) has optimized his setup to serve 10 million requests in a day off a micro-instance on AWS.

I think you should look at your server config first, then shop for other hosts. If you can't control server configuration, try AWS, Rackspace or other cloud services.

just an FYI: You can sign up for AWS and use a micro instance free for one year. The link I posted - he just optimized on the same server. You might have to upgrade to a small server because Amazon has stated that micro is only to handle spikes and sustained traffic.

Good luck.